# Get attribute from a xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml.in this xml I have a node named video like below

```
  <product>
 <id>676872</id>
  <weightingram>510</weightingram>
  <volume>0</volume>
  <discountgroup />
 <name>Product name (500 g)</name>
  <vat>10,49</vat>
  <webbestprice extra="webbestprice">0</webbestprice>
  <webreturn extra="webreturn">0</webreturn>
  <weboutdate extra="weboutdate">01-01-2013 00:00:00</weboutdate>
  <webaltitem extra="webaltitem" />
  <filters extra="filters">
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Type" FILTERNAME="type" UNITCODE=""/>
    <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Type2" FILTERNAME="500" UNITCODE="g"/>
  </filters>
  <videos extra="videos">
    <YoutubeVideoURL RowNumber="33" ProductID="676872" YoutubeUrl="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjoEIHVk9qM" YoutubeImage="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EjoEIHVk9qM/2.jpg"/>
  </videos>
</product>
```

the above xml is getting by using

```
<textarea>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</textarea>
```

I need to get the value of  attribute YoutubeUrl from this xml.I tried something like

```
 <xsl:value-of select="./videos/YoutubeVideoURL[@YoutubeUrl] "/>
```

but it is not working.Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You need to show more context in your XSL, one cannot guess at what context your are executing the xsl:value-of and therefore cannot even guess at what your problem is. Show the whole template.

Comment: I agree with @KevinBrown that you should have to provide your working XML contents so that others can get idea.

Comment: @Matthew Green please find the edit

Comment: @Arun; i have updated my ans an tested. Its retriving the value properly...Let me know what template you have set to retrive the YoutubeUrl value

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<xsl:template match="YoutubeVideoURL">
   <xsl:value-of select="@YoutubeUrl"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(or)

if you have specified the template that is matching to "/" root then use the below syntax.

```
<xsl:template match="/">

 .....
   <textarea>
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </textarea>
   <p>
   <xsl:value-of select="//videos//YoutubeVideoURL//@YoutubeUrl"/>
   </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Copy-of will copy the xml element specified in the select expression. So TextArea will have that xml element with its structure. And you are using value-of to retrive the xml attribute which needs an element selection. So, its not related.

You can use either of the solution mentioned in this ans.

Comment: I tried the second one .but not working.
<xsl:value-of select="./videos/YoutubeVideoURL@YoutubeUrl"/>

Comment: can you try without "./"? Start from videos. And did you tried the first one?

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="videos/YoutubeVideoURL@YoutubeUrl"/>

Comment: @Viji Your second example is not a valid XPath expression. You are missing a `/`.

Comment: @Arun: You can use this <xsl:value-of select="videos/YoutubeVideoURL/@YoutubeUrl"/> , I missed / in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this

Your sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<videos extra="videos">
    <YoutubeVideoURL RowNumber="1" ProductID="12452" YoutubeUrl="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efhrtgdbo" YoutubeImage="https://img.youtube.com/vi/efhrtgdbo/2.jpg"/>
</videos>
```

And your sample XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="YoutubeVideoURL">
        <xsl:value-of select="@YoutubeUrl"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Final output

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efhrtgdbo

That's it

Comment: But I have the xslt,in this xslt
<xsl:template match="product">
here i get the sample xml as i given in the question.here I need to get the YoutubeUrl value.
</xsl:template>

Comment: But you provided only `</video>` xml. So based on your sample I can only provide that answer. You have to show your working XML.

Comment: It is correct ..I said I can't call  <xsl:template match="YoutubeVideoURL"> inside <xsl:template match="product">

Comment: Try with this if you can access as per your XML structure : `<xsl:value-of select="./videos/YoutubeVideoURL/@YoutubeUrl"/>`

Answer (score 0):

In your value-of you are looking for any `videos/YoutubeVideoURL` that have an attribute of `@YoutubeUrl`. If you are looking to get the **value** of `@YoutubeUrl` then you need to take it out of the predicate like so.

```
<xsl:value-of select="./videos/YoutubeVideoURL/@YoutubeUrl" />
```

This of course assumes that your paths and templates are already set up correctly to locate this value at it's current position.

Comment: Yes When i Test 
<<xsl:value-of select="./videos> it get the result..
<YoutubeVideoURL RowNumber="29" ProductID="80182" YoutubeUrl="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjoEIHVk9qM" YoutubeImage="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EjoEIHVk9qM/2.jpg"/>

but Trying <xsl:value-of select="./videos/YoutubeVideoURL/@YoutubeUrl" /> it dosn't give any result? What is the Problem?

Comment: @Arun I don't know what the issue is without you providing more of your XML and XSL. When I take what you've shown for XML and transform it with my XSL that looks for the value I've specified I get the URL. Is the XML you've shown in an actual XML and not a result tree fragment?

Comment: yes I edited question please find.the xml is getting while <textarea><xsl:copy-of select="."/></textarea>

Comment: @Arun so you are copying the XML into a <textarea>? I'm not sure I understand. Can you show more of the XSL? That might help narrow down the problem. I think your XML must be a RTF but it's hard to tell based on the information. Of course this all assumes you are using XSLT 1.0 too.